# Django get_absolute_url queries

Tags: django, django-queryset

I use get_absolute_url in a sitemap template. Not the sitemap.xml, but a page in the site layout displaying all links. I basically get all page objects, and iter over them in the template, using get_absolute_url.

I discovered that for every link the database is hit one time. How do I reduce the queries?

I thought of two solutions, but I don't know which way is the best:

1. use the sitemap framework from Django. I know the sitemap framework uses the get_absolute_url as well. I was not able to check the amount of queries when a sitemap.xml is generated (debug toolbar doesn't show up).
2. write a custom save method, and save the url in the database, using get_absolute_url

Edit:

I use some simple code to generate the link page:

Views.py:

```
all_links = mypage.objects.all()
```

Template:

```
<ul>
{% for link in all_links %}
<li>li><a href="{{link.get_absolute_url}}">{{link.link_title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

models.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        if self.submenu:
            return "/%s/%s/" %(self.submenu.slug,self.slug)
        elif not self.mainmenu:
            return "/submenu/%s" % self.slug
        else:
            return "/%s/" % self.slug
```

Edit2:

I will turn on caching when in production. I think it is a good thing to optimize first.

Comment: If you have request object then you can use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) It won't hit your database even once

Comment: I want a list of all available urls of my site. I don't see how to use a request object for that?

Comment: We can't help if you don't show the code that is generating the queries.

Comment: There's more solutions, like caching or optimising your query that fetches all the objects, but without your code it's impossible to advise

Comment: Thank you for all replies. I have added the code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is important to use get_absolute_url,  because there should be no differences between sitemap.xml and my sitemap page. My solution, for now, is this (always open to better solutions)

I created a model field:

```
absolute_url = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, editable=False)
```

Then a custom save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.absolute_url = self.get_absolute_url()
        super(mypage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my template:

```
<ul>
     {% for link in all_links %}
           <li><a href="{{link.absolute_url}}">{{link.menu_title}}</a></li>
     {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This saved me a lot of queries. Now only one is used for the links (instead of 1 query per link)